# How to change keycodes to mouseclicks in flash/as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, mouseclick-event

I am trying to change the control of a game from keyboard events to a touch or mouseclick event, so i can publish the game to mobile. I am using Adobe Flash CS6, and the game is written in AS3. I have tried searching for what I am looking for ,but as I don't know how I should be wording this, I don't know what I'm looking for.

This is what I am trying to change. Any advice will be appreciated.

```js
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && myPause == false)
{
    // code, etc here
}
```

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html

This has all the touch events, so instead of listening to the KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, you will listen to TouchEvent. Are you going to give it an interface?

Answer (score 1):

MouseEvent.CLICK will be interpreted just fine when you publish AIR for iOS or Android.

So it's:

`yourTargetedObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, yourListenerFunction)`

and then:

```
function yourListenerFunction(e)
 {
   //do something here
 }
```